# Database Modeling: how to relate a book to its bindings?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, database-design

A particular book can have 0 or more related bindings (e.g. hardcover, paperback, etc.). So, say I have book `1` and it's related to books `2`, `3`, and `4`. I might have a table that looks like this:

```
book_id     related_book_id
1           2
1           3
1           4
```

Now, I think it also follows that book `2` is related to `1`, `3`, and `4`. So, I could expand the table records to include these:

```
book_id     related_book_id
2           1
2           3
2           4
```

... and do the same for `3` and `4`. Then do it for the million of books that exist in the market.

**Is this a good idea?** I see `(1,2)` as being the same as `(2,1)`.

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: There is a much better way.  I will provide an answer in the morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need two different types of entities: A Publication and a Title.  A publication would roughly be associated with an ISBN, which also ensures that different editions are uniquely identifiable.  A "title" entity would then be associated with multiple publications.

```
Title
-----------
TitleId int
AuthorId int
BookTitle nvarchar(500)
etc...

Publication
-----------
PublicationId int
CoverType char(1)
Edition nvarchar(50)
TitleId int (foreign key to Title)
etc...
```

Comment: +1. Answers the real problem, not just what the poster was asking.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your answer (perhaps with some sample tables)? It seems to me your solution is the same as mine, which I think might not be good.

Comment: what about titles that have more than one author?  Maybe an TitleAuthor table (many to many between authors and titles)?